# accessing DB array key/value outside switch

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, scope, switch-statement

I have a mysql table with questions IDs (q_ID) and answers (a_answer).  I want to use this data to populate some html later in the doc.  Some of the data is separated by '|' and I want to use switch to filter.  I am having trouble accessing the data by key. It works within while loop, but I need it outside.

```
$getData="SELECT a_answer, q_ID FROM answers ";

$result = mysqli_query($connected, $getData);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$arAnswer = explode('|', $row['a_answer']);

//catagorize by number of values    
$arrayCount = count($arAnswer);

switch ($arrayCount) 
{ 
case 1: //short data, no separators

//make array for ID and answer
$q = $row['q_ID'];
$a = $arAnswer[0];

$x = array($q=>$a);

break;

}; //END switch
}; //END while
```

Later in the doc, echo does not return value/$a for $q:

```
 echo $x[1]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are re-setting $x every time through the loop. The following would likely be a better solution:

```
$getData="SELECT a_answer, q_ID FROM answers ";

$result = mysqli_query($connected, $getData);

$x = array();         // Added this.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$arAnswer = explode('|', $row['a_answer']);

$arrayCount = count($arAnswer);

switch ($arrayCount) 
{ 
case 1:

$q = $row['q_ID'];
$a = $arAnswer[0];

$x[] = array($q=>$a); // Add [] after $x to push array($q=>$a) 
                      // onto the end of the $x array.
                      // You can also use array_push, but
                      // the technique here is quicker.

break;

};
};
```

**Edit**: To create a one-dimensional array, do the following:

```
$x[$q] = $a;
```

You need to do that in the while loop and still declare the $x array before the while loop.

Comment: that works but returns in an array with an array.  I was hoping to avoid that.  print_r  is 0] => Array
        (
            [4] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [5] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [6] => male
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [7] => 77777
        )

Comment: Well, how else are you going to store multiple rows of data in a variable if you don't use an array? You need to do something. You can create a one-dimensional array, if you want.

Comment: how would I create a one dimensional?

Comment: Excellent!  You make it look so easy - I've been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: Well, I have lots of practice. I struggled with the same sorts of things at first. You'll get used to it.